# Google Places API - quota increase (1000 to 150 000) only available for businesses?

Tags: google-places-api, talend, billing

I recently started an internship concerning Master Data Management in Talend. Part of the Master Data Management proces involves the cleansing of data. In my case I have to cleanse a few addresses. After doing some research I bumped into the Google Places API, which would do the trick for me. At first I wasn't aware of the so called quota limits that are bound to this API so I decided to read up on it some more. Basicly I have quite a few addresses to cleanse, so the 1000 requests per day limit won't cut it. As of yesterday I decided to increase that limit to 150 000 requests by verifying my identity using my creditcard. The requests were indeed increased to 150 000 but after a few hours my billing account was closed without warning and the limit went back to 1000 requests.

My question is: is the increase of the quota limit only available for businesses or are individual users eligible for it too?

I basicly filled in my own name as the name of the business when I created the billing account for my own project. That billing account is closed now. I really need that quota increase to be able to finish my project so I'm wondering if you guys are able to enlighten me. The image below is part of the form which has to be filled in to create a billing account.

[image: Google Developers billing form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this amount of quota you have to identify yourself through your credit card and thats it. you can use this key for personal use or business does not matter . as the whole app has that much of search quota. no matter how many people install that app.

so the answer is it is eligible for individual users too.

thank you

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Sagar! I still think it's weird that my billing account just gets closed without any kind of warning, even though I filled in the required credit card details. I tried it once more but my billing account just gets closed again after an hour or so.

Comment: did you get any conformation mail from google about this .

Comment: Just pondering this myself, looking forward to an official answer (or a big bill!)

Answer (score 0):

You may have different terms in your country.  We don't have VAT in the US, although we do have state-specific sales tax on some goods and services.  I suspect that Google cannot offer this service in your country without a business tracking the VAT for it.  I use the Google Search API with Custom Search Engines on both personal and business accounts from the US with just CC validation.  You might look to see if there are Google services resellers local to you who can offer you the Place API.